# 'create()' must be implemented

Tags: jquery, django, django-rest-framework

I'm quite new to Django and I'm using Apache Cassandra as my database. There's this one error I have when sending a form using jquery ajax.

> NotImplementedError at /chatdata/
>
> `create()` must be implemented.

Here's my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Chat
import uuid
from django.utils import timezone

class ChatSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    room_id = serializers.UUIDField()
    username = serializers.CharField()
    mac = serializers.CharField()
    message = serializers.CharField()
    created_at = serializers.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid1())
    ts_created = serializers.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
```

and here's my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Chat, Bulletin
from .serializers import ChatSerializer, BulletinSerializer

class ChatList(APIView):

    @csrf_exempt
    def get(self, request):
        chats = Chat.objects(Chat.room_id == "bbbcb63c-027e-427b-a6e5-b575a79de797").order_by("-created_at")
        serializer = ChatSerializer(chats, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ChatSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

lastly, my jquery to send the form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formchat').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
            type: "POST",
            header: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#chatinput").val('');
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Update:**
here's my models.py

```
import uuid
from django.utils import timezone
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from django_cassandra_engine.models import DjangoCassandraModel

class Chat(DjangoCassandraModel):
    room_id = columns.UUID(partition_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())
    username = columns.Text(required=True)
    mac = columns.Text(min_length=17, max_length=17, required=True)
    message = columns.Text(required=True)
    created_at = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid1(), required=True, clustering_order="DESC")
    ts_created = columns.DateTime(default=timezone.now())

    class Meta:
        get_pk_field = 'room_id'
```

Answer (score 8):

The error comes from [BaseSerializer](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L168)

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    raise NotImplementedError('`create()` must be implemented.')
```

The `serializers.Serializer` class is derived from `BaseSerializer` and it does not implement the `create()` method either. So you have to `create a create method` to save your model. Alternatively, consider using ModelSerializer instead.

Comment: I was using ModelSerializer at first (I was learning from video tutorials) but using Cassandra database gave me problems as DataStax's python driver has different field names as the Django's (e.g. models.CharField on Django is columns.Text on the cassandra driver). Even if I tried to match them on my serializers.py, it would still throw errors.

Comment: I did say on my first sentence I was using Apache Cassandra though. Haven't edited my question.

Comment: OOpos! really sorry my bad

Answer (score 8):

Use **serializers.ModelSerializer** instead of **serializers.Serializer**

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   ...fields here


    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = '__all__'
```

Refer to Restframework [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) section for guide to DRF.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the serializers, inorder to return complete object instances based on the validated data we need to implement one or both of the create() and update() methods. Please Follow the link [Saving Instance](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#Savinginstances)

## serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Chat
import uuid
from django.utils import timezone

class ChatSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    room_id = serializers.UUIDField()
    username = serializers.CharField()
    mac = serializers.CharField()
    message = serializers.CharField()
    created_at = serializers.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid1())
    ts_created = serializers.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Chart.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: Gave me this error:
`Exception Type: TypeError at /chatdata/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'`

Comment: When I tried using `return Chat.objects.create(**validated_data)` the problem now was that timestamp and the uuid1 never changes for some reason even with a page refresh.

Comment: Uuid will not change its unique for table. Timestamp is editable field or not ?

Comment: Timestamp's not editable via form. Just want to make it create a new timestamp every time new data comes in.

Comment: Can you share your models ? It's not clear with error message.

Comment: I've added my models at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Can you remove the default in the serializer level ? You added the default in the model level. No need to add in serializer level.

Comment: Removed the defaults on serializers but ts and uuid1 still doesn't change. Every time I send a chat message, it would just replace what I've sent the first time.

Comment: Can you please check you chat model ? You specified to primary keys. One table will have one primary key.